# LibreOffice slideshow only loops for a few minutes

Tags: raspbian

So I have a Raspberry Pi 4 set to auto-present an Impress slideshow, but only cycles the slides for about ~10-20 minutes then stays stuck on one slide. By clicking the mouse or arrow key, it then resumes and continues until it gets stuck on another slide. Does anyone know why it does this? Does the Pi go into a "sleep" mode? Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: did you ask this already? ... i think that i have seen this exact question, and one of the comments was to try opening  slideshow in another operating system, such as windows

Comment: @jsotola it operates fine on Windows. The problem is in the Pi

Comment: how do you know that it is not Linux?

Comment: Be more descriptive ! Raspberry Pi 4 is the hardware, OS, version of impress. And have you tried to make a "simple" impress slide to rule out that? So the question needs to be improved !